# how to change dock icon using setContentView to display one big character in mac os x

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift, dock

I want to change the dock icon of an app into one big character like an "A" or "B" for example using swift or objective C

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I want to change the dock icon of osx app to display text instead of an icon for a running app using swift or objective c and thanks for fast response

Comment: I tried a lot of code and not worked and searched the net for too long time with no avail so please help me it is really a big matter for me

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for [NSDockTile](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSDockTile_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDockTile/). It should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: I already read it and tried setViewContent in objective C and viewContent in swift but nothing worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    @IBOutlet weak var dockView: NSView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dockText: NSTextField!
    let appDockTile =  NSApplication.sharedApplication().dockTile

    func prepareDock(){
        appDockTile.contentView = dockView
        appDockTile.display()
    }
    func changeText(){
        dockText.stringValue = "B"
         appDockTile.display()
    }
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        prepareDock()

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    @IBAction func btnChangeText(sender: AnyObject) {
        changeText()
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot the code worked with me flawlessly. but how to change color and size of text in icon?

Comment: I knew how to change text size and color

Comment: just don't forget to call appDockTile.display() again after changing  your view, in this case your text color or size.

Answer (score 1):

my two cents for OSX  swift 4.x:

(make it flash..)

...

```
self.HeartBeatTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: DELTA_T, repeats: true, block: { (t: Timer) in

      let name = colored ? "heartbeat" : "heartbeat_red"
      let image = NSImage(named:  name)            
      let appDockTile =  NSApplication.shared.dockTile
      appDockTile.contentView = NSImageView(image: image!)
      appDockTile.display()
}
```