# Drag "functionality" from within a Mac App window onto the dock

Tags: macos

I have a Mac App and I need to be able to drag and drop certain "functionality" from within the app onto the main application dock. When the user later clicks the dock icon, it should launch another of my bundled applications. How can I implement that?

I already know how to create the new dock icons using a terminal script, but I am really stuck with the part where I need to animate the icon drag from the app window and onto the dock.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/docktasks_cocoa/docktasks_cocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000986-CH3-SW6

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/docktasks_cocoa/docktasks_cocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000986-CH3-SW6

Comment: Thanks Leonardo, but I need to add new dock icons and not just customize the existing app icon.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27156451/2303865

Comment: I already know how to create new dock icons using a terminal script, but I am really stuck with the part where I need to animate the icon drag from the app window and onto the dock. Thanks.

Comment: Adding Static Menu Items With a Nib File

If your application needs to add static items to the application’s Dock tile’s menu, you can provide those items in a nib file. To do this, perform the following steps.

Launch Interface Builder.
Create a new nib file for your menu.
Create a menu that includes the items you wish to add to the menu.
Connect the dockMenu outlet of the file’s owner (which by default is NSApplication) to your menu.
Add the nib name to the Info.plist, using the key AppleDockMenu. The nib name is specified without an extension.

Comment: I read it Leonardo and I don't need to add any dock icon static menu items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it, all you need to do is initiate a drag-and-drop operation with the file URL of your bundled application.  The Dock will automatically accept application URLs.

NSView has a [convenience method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac//documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/dragFile:fromRect:slideBack:event:) for performing file drag operations:

```
@implementation MyView

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent*)theEvent
{
    [self dragFile:@"/Applications/iTunes.app"
          fromRect:self.bounds
         slideBack:YES
             event:theEvent];
}

@end
```

See the [Dragging Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac//documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/DraggingFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001288-CEGJFDFG) reference for further info.